# Nodejs express routes in different files Express object automatically turns into a Router object

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, swagger

I have a Nodejs with express application. I register my routes using tsoa.
When i add swagger-ui-express to my nodejs application I get the following error `Error: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined`

I initialize the app as follows:

**app.ts**

```
  import config from './api/build/config';
    import express from 'express';
    
    
    function startServer() {
      const app = express();
    
      require('./api/loaders').default(app);
    
      app.listen(config.port, () => {
        console.log(`
          ################################################
          ️  Server listening on port: ${config.port}  ️ 
          ################################################
        `);
      });
    }
    
    startServer();
```

**loaders\index.ts**

```
import {Express} from 'express';

export default (app: Express) => {

  require('./express').default(app);
  console.log('✌️ Express loaded');

  require('./swagger').default(app);
  console.log('✌️ Swagger loaded');
};
```

**express.ts**

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import {Express, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import { RegisterRoutes } from '../routes';
import cors from 'cors';

export default function startExpress(app: Express) {
  app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(cors());

  //register all routes from the routes generated by tsoa
  RegisterRoutes(app);

  // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use((request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const error = new Error('404 Not Found');
      error['status'] = 404; 
      next(error);
  });

// error handlers
// error handler will print stacktrace only in development
  app.use((error: any, request: Request, response: Response) => {
    response.locals.message = error.message;
    response.locals.error = request.app.get('env') === 'development' ? error : {};
    response.status(error.status || 500);
    response.send(error.message);
  });

}
```

**swagger.ts**

```
import { Express } from 'express';
import swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';

export default function startSwagger(app: Express) {

    try{
        const swaggerDocument = require('../build/swagger.json');
        var options = {
          explorer: true
        };
        app.use('/swagger', swaggerUi.server, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, options));
    }
    catch(error){
        throw new Error(error);
    }

}
```

I also tried to use import statements instead of require, but it doesn't make a difference. Why does my compiler suddenly say my app Express object is a Router object and how do I set up nodejs with express and registering routes in different files?

Comment: add your router to the question\

Comment: Please share file where `RegisterRoutes` is defined. Also, full stack trace of error will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question...

> Why does my compiler suddenly say my app Express object is a Router object...

It doesn't. You can see a reference to the `Router.use()` function because it is just [eventually called](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/508936853a6e311099c9985d4c11a4b1b8f6af07/lib/application.js#L228) inside the `app.use()` function.

The actual issue here as mentioned in the error message is the middleware function being undefined. This is because inside your `swagger.ts` file, you specified `swaggerUi.server` as the middleware function but it needs to be changed to `swaggerUi.serve`.

```
import { Express } from 'express';
import swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';

export default function startSwagger(app: Express) {

    try{
        const swaggerDocument = require('../build/swagger.json');
        var options = {
          explorer: true
        };
        // The problem was here... change server to serve
        app.use('/swagger', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, options));
    }
    catch(error){
        throw new Error(error);
    }

}
```